# pointer from integer without a cast error

Tags: iphone, xcode, pointers, theos

can someone help me solve this error please? I've used this on another tweak i was working on and getting the intValue was no issue, but for some reason it is right now, I'm creating a WeeAppPlugin through theos

```
typedef enum {
    appleSMS = 0,
    biteSMSClient = 1
} WSSMSClient;

typedef enum {
    appleTwitter = 0,
    twitkaflyClient = 1
} WSTwitterClient;

static WSSMSClient *smsClient;
static WSTwitterClient *twitterClient;

- (void)loadSettings {
    [_settings release];
    _settings = [[NSDictionary alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:@"/var/mobile/Library/Preferences/com.michaelpoole.weesocial.plist"];
    smsClient = [[_settings objectForKey:@"smsClient"] intValue];
    twitterClient = [[_settings objectForKey:@"twitterClient"] intValue];
}
```

the error is

```
WeeSocialController.m:213: warning: assignment makes pointer from integer without a cast
WeeSocialController.m:214: warning: assignment makes pointer from integer without a cast
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this way, no need to make pointers to enum

```
static WSSMSClient smsClient;
static WSTwitterClient twitterClient;
```

Comment: Thank you, lol, i knew it was something small i was overlooking, i should have realized that, brain fart lol

Comment: sometimes it happens :) many a times i created int *i=10; and only after compiling confused, whats the error!!!